# Need help comparing the 13" 2016 MBP with the 15" 2015 MBP

Tags: macbook-pro

My current MacBook (13" early 2011 model)is old and showing signs of ageing. As new the new MacBook Pros have just launched, the prices are quite high. Last evening I visited a store and found out the 15" mid-2015 model is cheaper than the 13" late-2016 (Touch Bar) model. As I do lot of software development work, and use Xcode and Android Studio, along with localhost server work, I just wanted to know if the 15" will handle this type of world well? Sometimes I also do movie editing and steam gaming too.

I would be using the new laptop for a minimum of 3 years.

**Models:**

- 13-inch (2016)
- Intel Core i5-6267U @ 2.9 GHz
- 512GB HD
- 8GB RAM (2133 MHz)

---

- 15-inch (2015)
- Intel Core i7-4870HQ @ 2.50 GHz
- 512GB HD
- 16GB RAM (1600 MHz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really gets down to personal preference and in that sense your question will invite people to express opinions, rather than providing an answer to a problem.

The best way for you (and I dare say anyone) to make a decision is to identify what are the most important requirements for your intended use. For example:

- **CPU** - The 15" mid-2015 MacBook Pro has a 4 core processor, while the 13" late-2016 MacBook Pro only has a 2 core processor, so if processing power is critical the mid-2015 model is a better choice.
- **Battery** - The 13" late-2016 MacBook Pro, by virtue of its smaller screen size, will run longer on battery than the 15" mid-2015 MacBook Pro, so if running on battery power is critical, the 13" model is a better choice.
- **RAM** - The 13" late-2016 MacBook Pro you're considering has 8GB RAM, while the 15" mid-2015 MacBook Pro has 16GB RAM, so if the apps you run are memory hungry, then the mid-2015 model is a better choice.
- **Display** - The 15" mid-2015 MacBook Pro has a 15" screen (obviously) which has a native resolution of 2880x1800 pixels, while the 13" late-2016 MacBook Pro only has a 13" screen 2560x1600 pixels, so if the amount of desktop real estate is critical the mid-2015 model is a better choice.
- **Weight** - The 15" mid-2015 MacBook Pro weighs 2.04Kg while the 13" late-2016 MacBook Pro weighs 1.37Kg, so if you're going to be carrying it around a lot, then the 13" model is a better choice.
- **Ports** - It's well documented that the 13" late-2016 MacBook Pro has four USB-C ports and a 3.5mm headphone jack. The mid-2015 model on the other hand has two USB 3.0 ports, two Thunderbolt 2 ports, an HDMI port, an audio in/out port, and an SDXC card slot. Only you can decide which one is a better choice for the next three years!

You get the idea. Basically you need to decide your most important requirements and then do a comparison based on that.

Comment: This is a good answer to a shopping question.   I suggest that he also go to Everymac.com for detailed specs on various models.